# Example Database for OLAP Project

Tags: database, olap

I'm already looking for example databases for 2 weeks now, but i can't find anything. A schoolmate of mine and me are looking for an example-database for a project we are writing at school this year. We want to use some **OLAP**-Functions like "Slicing", "Dicing" and so on, so we would need a big, multidimensional database. 
Any advices where to look for them? We don't really want to create one like this on our own, we don't really have the time for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can download teh Adventure Works **DW** database for SQL Server from http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330. I have never tested it, but I would think that this should work with the free Express version of SQL Server. Analysis Services, however, can only be used in the paid versions of SQL Server. For OLAP, make sure you download the **DW** version of the samples.

I would think that other software providers have similar samples, like the following links show:

- https://forums.oracle.com/message/2293417
- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idm/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sampledata.go.doc%2Ftopics%2Fdownload.html

And I am sure there are samples for other DBMSes as well.